# netfilter2.sys driver automatically unregistered during reboot in WinVista/Win10

Tags: windows, drivers, netfilter

During install of our software package (NSIS as Admin), I write netfilter2.sys (which has been digitally signed) to c:\Windows\system32\drivers and register it for analyzing http packets.  It then returns when executing "driverquery" from cmd with all other registered drivers.  All functionality works fine, and seems to be all good.

However, after a reboot in WinVista(x86) and Win10 (x64), sporadically it will be unregistered, and no functionality will work.  It will still be present in c:\Windows\system32\drivers, but will no longer be returned when executing "driverquery".

After a reboot where it is unregistered, in Event Viewer, Windows Logs\System, we see a reference to netfilter2.sys, saying that "Windows Defender Real-Time Protection agent has taken action to protect this machine from spyware or other potentially unwanted software."

I then look at Windows Defender History log, and see that it was "permitted", but do not see it under either allowed programs or quarantined programs.

Any idea why this driver is being unregistered, and how to prevent it from being unregistered in the future?

Answer (score 0):

The issue stemmed from unregistering (-u tag) the driver and registering it directly after in the same batch file.

Apparently, when you unregister a driver like that it marks it for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Try a clean reinstall of Windows 10 to fix this issue we.